# Is the process dictionary appropriate in this case?

Tags: erlang

I've read several comments here and elsewhere suggesting that Erlang's process dictionary was a bad idea and should die. Normally, as a total Erlang newbie, I'd just avoid it. However, in this situation my other options aren't great.

I have a main dispatcher function that looks something like this:

```
dispatch(State) ->
    receive
        {cmd1, Params} ->
            NewState = do_cmd1_stuff(Params, State),
            dispatch(NewState);
        {cmd2, Params} ->
            NewState = do_cmd2_stuff(Params, State),
            dispatch(NewState);
        BadMsg ->
            log_error(BadMsg),
            dispatch(State)
    end.
```

Obviously, my names are more meaningful to me, but that's the gist of it. Deep down in a function called by a function called by a function called by do_cmd2_stuff(), I want to send out messages to all my users telling them about something I've done. In order to do that, I need to get the list of users from the point where I send the messages. The user list doesn't lend itself easily to sticking in the global state, since that's just one data structure representing the only block of data on which I operate.

The way I see it, I have a couple unpleasant options other than using the process dictionary. I can send the user list through all the various levels of functions down to the very bottom one that does the broadcasting. That's unpleasant because it causes all my functions to gain a parameter, whether they really care about it or not.

Alternatively, I could have all the `do_cmdN_stuff()` functions return a message to send. That's not great either though, since sending the message may not be the last thing I want to do and it clutters up my dispatcher with a bunch of `{Msg, NewState}` tuples. Furthermore, some of the functions might not have any messages to send some of the time.

Like I said earlier, I'm very new to Erlang. Maybe someone with more experience can point me at a better way. Is there one? Is the process dictionary appropriate in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general rule is that if you have doubts, you shouldn't use the process dictionary.

If the two options you mentioned aren't good enough (I personally like the one where you return the messages to send) and what you want is some particular piece of code to track users and forward messages to them, maybe what you want to do is have a process holding that info.

```
Pid ! {forward, Msg}
```

where `Pid` will take care of sending everything to a bunch of other processes. Now, you would still need to pass the Pid around, unless you give it a name in some registry to find it. Either with `register/2`, `global` or `gproc`.

Comment: @I GIVE TERRIBLE ADVICE: re your name: I beg to differ :P

Answer (score 4):

A simple answer would be to nest your global within a state record, which is then threaded through the system, at least at the stop level. This makes it easy to add new fields to the state in the future, not an uncommon occurrence, and allow you to keep your global state data structure untouched. So initially

```
-record(state, {users=[],state_data}).
```

Defining it as a record makes it easy to access and extend when necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Zed for fixing the typo.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you can always pass the user list as extra param, thats not so bad.

If you don't want to do this just put it in State.  You can have a special State just for this part of the calculation that also contains the user list.

Then there always is the possibility of putting it in ETS or in another server process.

What exactly to do is hard to recommend since it depends a lot on your exact application and preferences.

Just choose from the mentioned possibilities as if the process dictionary doesn't exist.  Maybe your code needs restructuring if none of the variants look elegant, there always is some better way without the process dictionary.

Its really bad it is still there, because its alluring to many beginning Erlang users.

Answer (score 1):

You really should not use process dictionary. I accept using dictionary only if

1. It is short living process.
2. I have full control about the process from spawn to termination i.e. I use minimum and well known set of external modules.
3. I need performance gain badly. It means avoid copy of data when using ets and dict/gb_tree is too slow (for GC reason).

ad 1. is not your case, you are using in server. ad 2. I don't know if it is your case. ad 3. is not your case because you need list of recipient so you don't gain nothing from that process dictionary is very fast key/value storage. In your case I don't see any reason why you should not include what you need to your `State`. IMHO `State` is exactly the right place for it.

Answer (score 1):

Its an interesting question because it involves the fundamentals of functional design.

My opinion:
Try as much as possible to make the function return the messages, then send them. This separates the two different tasks nicely, and separates the purely functional task from the one that causes side effects.

If this isn't possible, pass receivers as argument even if its a bit messy. If the broadcasting function uses that data, it should be given to it explicitly, for clarity and predictability.

Using ETS as Peer Stritzinger suggests is really not any better than the PD, both hides the fact that the broadcasting function uses the receiver list and makes it dependent on global data.

I'm not sure about the Erlang way of encapsulating some state in a process, as I GIVE TERRIBLE ADVICE suggests. Is it really any better that ETS or PD?

> clutters up my dispatcher with a bunch
>   of {Msg, NewState}

This is my experience also, that you often end up like this. It's not particularly pretty, but functional design seems to encourage this. Could some language feature be introduced to make it more beautiful and natural?

### EDIT:

6 years ago I wrote:

> Could some language feature be introduced to make it more beautiful and natural?

After learning much more about functional programming I have realised that examples of this are state-monads and [do-notation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation) that are found in Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider sending a special message to `self()` from deep inside the call stack, and handling it at the top level `dispatch` method that you've sketched, where list of users is available.